# android - incomplete async task with fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

I have a content fragment which contains a gridview and populating gridview with async task.

I have three button which creates same fragment with different values and when button 1 creates fragment and start AsyncTask, I click button 2 before it finish task , it throws null pointer exception at adapter `getCount()` function.

```
        Example
        Button 1 > new DFragment("Cars");
        Button 2 > new DFragment("Bikes");
        Button 3 > new DFragment("Shoes");
```

When you click button 1 , then click button 2 immediately ,it throws nullpointer exception at BaseAdapter.

*How i can solve that and cancel old AsyncTask if new instance of fragment created ?*

Thanks

Comment: you should probably override the on cancel function of async task and use it to your need (so it wont go to on post execute the main ui thread)

Comment: i am keeping async task in a static object and controlling if it is running , cancel if yes